# SQL query for obtain correct retarded dept in a report

Tags: sql, ms-access, accounting

There's a payment table with these fields:

1. Dossier_id
2. Year
3. Amount
4. Payed
5. Retarded
   ( all fields are numeral )

Imagine the table with these entries:

```
    Dossier_id ||   Year   ||     Amount    ||    Payed    || Retarded
    ==================================================================
     1000           2010           500           100          400
     2000           2007           700           500          200
     1000           2011           1200          700          500
     2000           2009           900           800          100
    ==================================================================
              Total        ||      3300          2100         600
    ==================================================================
```

How can i write a query to calculate (only) the end section of that table (Total) to achieve the correct Retarded rate as total liability? ( i played with inner join but i couldn't figure it well)

Comment: that sort of depends on how you get 600?

Comment: because in next year he/she payed the retarded amount and we should calculate only last retarded in last year.

Comment: is the total per Dossier_id or Sum of all? Your Retarded Total should be double that unless you're averaging? You could be a bit more specific ..

Comment: @MilenPavlov : Sum of all

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
SELECT SUM(a.amount), sum(a.payed), b.retarded
FROM table a INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(retarded) AS retarded
               FROM table b INNER JOIN (SELECT dossier_id, MAX(year) FROM table) c ON b.dossier_id = c.dossier_id AND b.year = c.year) b ON 1 = 1
```

EDIT (stupid access - [join not supported issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/15c36745-f7a4-4926-9687-7161e5894468/join-expression-not-supported-error-caused-by-unbracketed-join-expression-comprising-string)):

```
SELECT SUM(a.amount), sum(a.payed), b.retarded
FROM table a INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(retarded) AS retarded
               FROM table b INNER JOIN (SELECT dossier_id, MAX(year) FROM table) c ON (b.dossier_id = c.dossier_id AND b.year = c.year)) b ON (1 = 1)
```

Comment: SELECT p1.paySUM,p2.retardedSUM FROM
 (SELECT sum(payed) as paySUM FROM payment WHERE year<=maxyear) p1,
 (SELECT sum(retarded) as retardedSUM FROM payment WHERE year = maxyear ) p2

Comment: Join expression not supported

Comment: Join expression not supported again! it works with that query i sent. thanks for your attention alotttt

Answer (score -1):

Its this simple query:

```
SELECT    SUM(AMOUNT), SUM(PAYED), SUM(RETARDED) FROM TABLE;
```

Comment: Try ROLLUP and GROUPING clauses.